# Share data file (yml) between 2 GitLab projects

Tags: curl, gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

I have 2 GitLab projects (static sites), that need to share the same yaml file. Currently the yaml file exists in project A, and project B manually clones it every week or so. I want to be able to have an automated solution that doesn't require manual synchronization. I need the data to be accessible in both local development and production.

Some ideas:

1. Host the file on GitLab pages from A and curl it into B.
2. Set up an access token and use [gitlab-api](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html#get-raw-file-from-repository), curl it into B.
3. Say screw it, and build out a proper API that feeds both repos.

Is there a solution that's better that I'm not thinking about? What would you do? I'm leaning towards option 2.

Answer (score 0):

Automation in GitLab is synonym of pipelines.

Add a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file in the root folder of project B with the following content:

```yaml
stages:
  - synchronize

include:
  - local: /.ci/synchronize.yml
```

In project root folder create ./.ci/synchronize.yml with the following content:

```yaml
synchronize-job:
  stage: synchronize
  image: ubuntu:jammy-20220428 
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule" # run job only for a scheduled pipeline

  script:
    - |
        apt-get update # update repo
        apt-get install --yes curl git # install tools
    - git clone -b main https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@<your_server_domain>/<project A>.git
    - cp <project A name>/<your yml file>.yml .
    - git remote rm origin && git remote add origin git@<your_server_domain>:<project B path>.git
    - git push -u origin main
```

Then [create a scheduled pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/schedules.html) from the GitLab GUI. Specify the interval of one week, as you desire.

In this solution, you have:

- automation;
- no manual creation of auth token: the GITLAB_CI_TOKEN is automatically created and destroyed with the job;
- synchronization.

Caveat: if you include other jobs in the pipeline, they may be triggered in an infinite loop due to the final push in synchronize-job. Just configure the rules of these jobs to not run when there's a push on main branch.